# Virtualize Win10 partition from Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, windows, virtualization

I am about to try to virtualize the Windows 10 partition that I am currently using in a dual boot setup on my Dell XPS13.

### *Background story...*

As it is the developer edition, it comes with Ubuntu pre-installed. I have installed Windows 10 afterwards, creating a partition on the drive. Still, I managed to have a fully-functioning dual boot with the pre-installed Ubuntu and Windows 10. I only had to use boot-repair to make GRUB see both partitions (I tried a manual fix that didn't work...).

**Now I want to virtualize the same Win10 partition from Ubuntu**, which would be very handy from time to time (e.g., I work with PSoC microcontrollers and the software is Windows-only). This topic is well documented online, but I have few doubts and I don't want to screw things up.

Here is the list of partitions of my drive (NMVE SSD btw) from `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Device             Start        End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    1599487   1597440  780M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1599488   12085247  10485760    5G Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3  12085248  882454527 870369280  415G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p4 882454528 1000214527 117760000 56,2G Microsoft basic data
```

Please mind that **p1, p2 and p3 were already present before the dual boot**. I added the 4th partition shrinking the 3rd one. So I have no idea what's inside the *5 GiB Microsoft reserved* partition (side question: can I remove it?).

I was looking at the [VirtualBox advanced user manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk) and I found that we can now specify the partitions that the virtual disk can access. For example, the command

```
$ VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename \
/path/to/file.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sda -partitions 1,5
```

> (...) is identical to the one for full hard disk access, except for the additional -partitions parameter. This example would create the image /path-to-file.vmdk, which must be absolute, and partitions 1 and 5 of /dev/sda would be made accessible to the guest.

### *...and my question is*

So, in my case, **would I need to specify something like: `-partitions p1,p4`. Do I need `p1`?** That would the one with the EFI bootloader, I guess? I'm not sure where the Win10 bootloader would be, actually.

I hope I have provided enough details to explain my doubts and *help you help me*. Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*/dev/nvme0n1p1 780 M EFI System* is required to boot in an (U)EFI system, whether Windows or Linux.  **You must have it.**

*/dev/nvme0n1p2  5 G Microsoft reserved* is a Windows Recovery partition. Once p4 is virtualized, you can eliminate it.

*/dev/nvme0n1p3  415 G Linux filesystem* That's Ubuntu OS and Ubuntu data.

*/dev/nvme0n1p4 56.2G Microsoft basic data*  This is the NTFS partition which contains the Windows OS and Windows data. **This is the only thing you need to virtualize**. You may wish to copy some of your data to your Ubuntu partition; documents and media files (music, movies, ebooks, and pictures) before you virtualize it, but that's a personal choice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to understand things better, I guess that to be able to *both* virtualize and boot the Windows partition, I would have to run the command with -partitions p1,p4. Is that right? Also, why would you suggest to keep the files off windows? Right now I have just installed a couple of softwares and I have zero data there. I was planning on doing so, just curious if there’s a reason.

Comment: I tried creating the virtual disk and that went ok, but now the VM does not boot. I created a boot.iso copying GRUB and it says _FATAL no bootable medium found_
Any ideas? @K7AAY

Comment: No ideas, sorry. Greater minds than mine will need to help.